# Laravel 6: User models uses UUID instead of auto-increment. Where to update DB session logic?

Tags: php, laravel

OK so my User models uses `webpatser/laravel-uuid`. All migrations are using UUID.

So now my model looks like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Models\Traits\Uuid;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    use Uuid;

    public $incrementing = false;
    public $timestamps = true;

    protected $guarded = [
        'uuid',
    ];

    protected $keyType = 'string';
    protected $primaryKey = 'uuid';
    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $dates = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    public function setPasswordAttribute($password): void
    {
        $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($password);
    }
}
```

[image]

I want to use database session driver. I created session table via `php artisan session:table`. All migrations are done. I obviously had to rename existing `user_id` column. I've changed it to `user_uuid`. I know it's not enough as I can't find the logic responsible for populating this db table. I guess it's somewhere in the `vendor` (Illuminate).

Where is the logic to populate my non-default session column?

[image]

Now each open the page gives:

[image]

So I know what's the issue, what's causing it, how to change it, but I don't know where to start. Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would benefit of a custom session handler because the name of the column `user_id` is hardcoded into the `addUserInformation()` method.

Extend the existing [DatabaseSessionHandler.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Session/DatabaseSessionHandler.php) and replace the `addUserInformation()` method so it looks for the correct column name:

```
class DatabaseUuidSessionHandler extends DatabaseSessionHandler
{
    protected function addUserInformation(&$payload)
    {
        if ($this->container->bound(Guard::class)) {
            $payload['user_uuid'] = $this->userId();
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Register it in one of your service providers:

```
class SessionServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        Session::extend('databaseUuid', function ($app) {
            return new DatabaseUuidSessionHandler;
        });
    }
}
```

Finally update `SESSION_DRIVER` in your .env to use the newly created `databaseUuid` driver.

Remember that this is untested code and should only be used as a guideline of how this could work.